# How to access buffer data of Kinect version 2 (Color and IR)

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am developing an application to calculate heart rate of a person by analysing facial skin color changes occuring with heart beat. I am using a Kinect version 2 camera with C# (visual studio 2013). I understand that when a color frame or IR frame comes, the pixel data is being stored somewhere. My belief is that these data can be used to derive heart rate. I do not know how to access this data. Can somebody please help? 
(I am new to Kinect as well as C#)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new in both Kinect and C#, I'd at first suggest you to go through the samples provided with Kinect SDK. A program named SDK Browser (Kinect for windows) V2 has installed along with the Kinect SDK. You will find lots of samples there. Hope it helps.

Secondly,

To get color data, you can use of these following methods under [`ColorFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.aspx) class.

1. [`CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.copyconvertedframedatatoarray.aspx)
2. [`CopyConvertedFrameDataToBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.copyconvertedframedatatobuffer.aspx)
3. [`CopyRawFrameDataToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.copyrawframedatatoarray.aspx)
4. [`CopyRawFrameDataToBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.colorframe.copyrawframedatatobuffer.aspx)

For IR Data, there's the following 2 methods under [`InfraredFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.infraredframe.aspx) class.

1. [`CopyFrameDataToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.infraredframe.copyframedatatoarray.aspx)
2. [`CopyFrameDataToBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.infraredframe.copyframedatatobuffer.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I will try these.

Comment: I used the copyRawFrameDataToArray method inside kinect's sample file Colorbasics.

Comment: I used the copyRawFrameDataToArray method inside kinect's sample file Colorbasics-WPF like this 
Inside public partial class main window I initialized a byte array like this   private byte[] myColorData = null;
 and inside Reader_ColorFrameArrived method, inside  if (colorFrame != null), 
  colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(this.myColorData);

It does not give any build errors but it gives an ArgumentNullException. 

What I want to do is to save the color data during the time the program is running in an array. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I also tried with private byte[] myColorData without initializing it to null. Still I get the same exception.

Comment: You have to allocate proper memory to `myColorData`. I think you have to do something like `myColorData = new byte [bytes_per_pixel * width * height]`

Comment: I don't remember the exact value of `bytes_per_pixel`, `width` or `height` for colorData

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code as this

 byte[] myColorData = new byte[colorFrame.FrameDescription.BytesPerPixel * colorFrame.FrameDescription.Height * colorFrame.FrameDescription.Width];
                        colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(this.myColorData);

                        for (int i = 0; i < myColorData.Length; i++) {
                            Console.WriteLine(myColorData[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(myColorData.Length);

When I print it it is all zeros and the length shows as 4147200 value I used in initialization.

Comment: although kinect opens, there is no output showing (just black). Is it a fault with this code or kinect camera?

Comment: when I don't try to print, it gives the usual output. But I need to see whether the data has been saved in the array. that is why i am trying to print.